# Why does mysql require filesort when the order by col has an index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization, mysql-5.5

I create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `test_updated_at_index` (`updated_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And the explain on a select says that it is using filesort:

```
mysql> explain select * from testtable order by updated_at;
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | testtable | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
```

Why does it not use the index? Additionally, if I just remove the created_at column, then it DOES use the index!

Why does adding a single additional column cause mysql to forget how to use the index?

How can I change the table so that mysql DOES use the index to order by, even with an additional column?

Answer (score 0):

There is no WHERE clause, so you read all records from the table. Most often it is way faster to read the table directly, even if you must sort the data afterwards, rather than looping over an index and picking each record separately.

Only if you were interested only in a small part of the table, say 2% of its data, would it make sense to use the index. Or if you were only interested in the indexed column alone, of course.

Comment: Not sure that follows. The whole point of an index is that the values are already sorted in it. Reading out the contents of a tree in order is always going to be more efficient than sorting an unsorted list - e.g. O(n) vs O(nlogn)

Comment: What sounds better: 1) Read a file (the table) from from disk, sort it, show the data. 2) Read one record from a file (the index), use the information to read one record from another file (the table), read the next record from the first file (the index), use this information to read a record from the other file (the table), and so on and on and on.

Comment: The data in the table is unsorted, so you may have to read physical block A for the first record, physical block Z for the second, block A again for the next, then block B, A, Z, B, ... So you must fetch the same data blocks again and again from disk. With a sequential read, you read block A, B, ... Z, each only once. And it is usually disk access which is most costly when accessing data in a database.

Comment: An index is great when you want to read few records only, so you don't have to read all physical blocks of the table usually. Or when the index itself already contains all columns you are interested in, so you don't have to read the table at all.

Comment: Ok, first: You don't need to fetch the same blocks, because once you fetch them the first time, they are in memory. Repeatedly fetching the index file is a) very poor design, and b) not the responsibility of a userspace program - it should be up to the filesystem/kernel to implement a sane caching method. For your actual point, I cannot understand why you think that reading data in order and sorting them in memory is faster than reading them out of order and then not having to sort. Not to mention, that if the table doesn't fit in memory, then your filesort has to do a bunch of extra writes!

Comment: Even if I add a where clause, it still doesn't use the index, although it does get listed as a possible key it does not actually get used.

Comment: Well, of course all this depends on the table size, the disk size, the available memory and cache etc. But it serves as a rule of thumb; full table scans are often quicker than index access and it's up to the DBMS to decide which method to pick. I've explained what might make a DBMS go for a full table scan in your case. Did you try `where updated_at in (<some date>, <some other date>)`? I am pretty sure the index would be used for such query, provided that one day only affects few rows and that the DBMS has statistics on the index.

Comment: "fetching the index block" -- since the blocks are "cached", that may or may not involve hitting the disk.  "Hitting the disk" is the most time-consuming thing that can be done in a query.  If the table and index(es) are small enough to fit in cache, then eventually (not the first time after a reboot), there will be no I/O.  But for a table/index bigger than cache, there will be lots of I/O.  The optimizer (currently) does not know whether things are cached, so it does not necessarily pick the "right" approach.

Comment: "even when I add a where clause" -- It's not just adding a `WHERE`.  It is (1) a `WHERE` that can use an index, and (2) selecting less than ~20% of the rows.  (The typical cutoff is somewhere around 10-30%; more than Thorsten's 2%.)

Comment: @RickJames so, it would use the index to select the rows for the where, and then do a filesort on the selection?

Comment: @Benubird: Your index contains one column only. So if you had a WHERE condition on it, the DBMS might decide to use it and would even get the data sorted right away. If your WHERE condition was on another column, the index would not be used, of course. Rick is right about a typical threshold of 10 to 30%, but I've seen it to be low as 0,002% on a big table (millions of rows) in another DBMS. So this really depends. And it is nothing we should worry about; the DBMS usually chooses the best plan to get to the desired data. This can be via an index or not; both is possible.